# How to do_action after some plugin{woocs} loaded?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i am working on simple feature: quantity change -> total price update on a single page. Solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31829032/372212

Works almost as i want except it doesnt work for variation products with a woocs plugin(currency switcher) installed altogether. I was trying to find out how woocs plugin get's price and only found this lines of code:

```php
$customer_price_format = get_option('woocs_customer_price_format', '__PRICE__');
```

Digging into that part and searching for **woocs_customer_price_format** gave me no positive results. Why would i need this price ? Because getting price with $product->get_price() - gets wrong price from price variations.

Only solution (actually its bad) i found is to regexp price from a field that woocs plugin is setting on product page. But that's a problem for me, because i don't know how to run code **AFTER** woocs plugin loaded.

Tried do_action('wp_loaded|plugins_loaded|after_cart_etc_all_hooks'), but for some time div with woocs plugin classname is undefined.

Is there an action to fire after all plugins loaded in woocommerce ?

Comment: "Because getting price with $product->get_price() - gets wrong price from price variations."
You should get the variations first (from $product) and get the price for each of them.  
About the WC hook, as you said, it's not a good practice, but the hook you are looking for may be this one: [`woocommerce_init`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WooCommerce.html#546)

Comment: thx for asnwer but its all wrong. hook must be about woocs plugin as it loads after woocommerce_init, i already managed to get all variations and find default one. but i cannot use it right time